# Prevent array filter from matching elements that do not have the same index as desired element

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have created a score ticker that highlights the winner of each game by adding a class `.winner` via the following JavaScript:

```
  // take max score from each game and push into g1winner and g2winner arrays - 
  g1winner.push(Math.max(parseInt(scoreboxArr[i].split(';')[2]),parseInt(scoreboxArr[i].split(';')[5]))); 
  g2winner.push(Math.max(parseInt(scoreboxArr[i].split(';')[11]),parseInt(scoreboxArr[i].split(';')[14])));

  // filter scorebox-elem's for each date to find max score and addClass '.winner'
  $('#g1t1_score.scorebox-elem, #g1t2_score.scorebox-elem').filter(function () {
    return $(this).is(':contains('+g1winner[i]+')');
  }).addClass('winner').prevAll().eq(2).addClass('winner');

  $('#g2t1_score.scorebox-elem, #g2t2_score.scorebox-elem').filter(function () {
    return $(this).is(':contains('+g2winner[i]+')');
  }).addClass('winner').prevAll().eq(2).addClass('winner');
```

The score ticker allows users to navigate left and right to view game score by date. The highlighting of the winning teams (via the `addClass` method) was working great until I had a losing team have the same score as a previous winning team from a different date. Observe:

[image]

[image]

You can see it in action here: https://cbnmensbasketball.weebly.com/.

I understand why this is happening, but I'm an amateur programmer and I'm not sure how I can alter what I have, so that only the current game's winning teams are matched by the `filter` function. Maybe add a counter that is tied to each `scorebox-grid` (the white `div`s above) and add in the condition that the index of the element in each array must match the counter? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you take a look at the **[`.filter()` jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)**, you can see that, its `callback` function has two params, the first one is the `index` of the treated `element`:

> **function**
>
> Type: `Function`( Integer `index`, Element `element` ) => Boolean
>
> A function used as a test for each element in the set. this is the
>   current DOM element.

So what to do here is to pass this `index` in the callback function and compare it with your `i` variable, so it takes only the relevant `element` into account:

```
$('#g2t1_score.scorebox-elem, #g2t2_score.scorebox-elem').filter(function (index) {
    return index == i && $(this).is(':contains('+g2winner[i]+')');
  }).addClass('winner').prevAll().eq(2).addClass('winner');
```